# Unable to connect to django 1.11 web app on Apache server

Tags: python, django, apache

I am no expert on Django. I am able to run the app on my local machine well. I want to deploy this app on our internal server. 
Versions I am using: Python: 2.7, Django 1.11, Apache: 2.4
Ports Open: 9991

When I access the port from any machine, it gives me no error. For e.g. xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:9991 shows Apache page.

But when I add the URL to the app 
    xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:9991/WebApp1Url
it gives error. 
Below is my configuration of httpd.conf

```
Listen 9991
<VirtualHost *:9991>
Alias /static "C:/xxx/DjangoSite/WebApps/WebApp1/static"
<Directory "C:/xxx/DjangoSite/WebApps/WebApp1/static">
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xxx/DjangoSite/WebApps/WebApps">
<Files wsgi.py>
 Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Below is my wsgi.py:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "WebApps.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
from WebApp1.wsgi import WebApp1
application = WebApp1(application)
```

settings.py contains:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'WebApps.wsgi.application'
```

I can assure that the paths to static and wsgi.py are correct. I can't figure out what is not right. Can someone please provide pointers as to which step is missing? Any help is appreciated. Pardon any typos above. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the error when accessing `xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:9991/WebApp1Url`?

Comment: The requested URL was not found on this server

Comment: You don't seem to have a wsgiscriptalias to serve your actual site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first stop for any problems, new user or experienced, should be Django's very detailed, extensive, up-to-date, versioned documentation. There's even a section for [deploying a Django project with Apache HTTPD](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

Some stuff quoted below, but broadly:

1. Install Apache HTTPD with mod_wsgi (installing the module on Windows is probably the hard part, the mod_wsgi docs link to [this guide](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst))
2. Add WSGI directives to a conf file

> The [official mod_wsgi documentation](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/) is your source for all the details about how to use mod_wsgi. You’ll probably want to start with the [installation and configuration documentation](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installation.html).
>
> ### Basic configuration
>
> Once you’ve got mod_wsgi installed and activated, edit your Apache server’s `httpd.conf` file and add the following. If you are using a version of Apache older than 2.4, replace `Require all granted` with `Allow from all` and also add the line `Order deny,allow` above it.
>
> ```
> WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
> WSGIPythonHome /path/to/venv
> WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com
>
> <Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
> <Files wsgi.py>
> Require all granted
> </Files>
> </Directory>
> ```

Comment: Thanks Nick T. I am trying to get mod_wsgi installed. Facing some problems there, as I dont have control over the Apache version installed. I will try out the rest.